Why does $\frac{1}{n!}$ correct Taylor Series from overshooting the target value?
What is the sum of the infinite series $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$?
From siulations in Python, it appears to converge on approximately 1.718. But I'm not certain how to evaluate it analytically because it is not a geometric series or p-series.
The broader context is of course understanding why the Taylor Series includes scaling by $\frac{1}{n!}$. I see that this scaling factor mitigates the explosive growth in scalar values due to recursive differentiation.
$nx^{n-1} + n(n-1)x^{n-2}+n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}+...$
But this isn't a very satisfying answer. However, knowing that $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$ does converge on some value is helpful; I had been interpreting the Taylor Series as the function itself plus a weighted average of its derivatives. But since $\Sigma_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \neq 1$, this interpretation is wrong.
Considering physics of a ball thrown up in the air. The function $f(t)$ returns the height, $h$, at a time, $t$. The first derivative, $f'(t)$, velocity, is not in $h$ but $\frac{h}{t}$. So to extract the change in $h$ attributable due to change in velocity, we need $tf'(t)$. Likewise, acceleration is in units $\frac{h}{t^2}$, thus to extract $h$ attributable to acceleration, we need $t^2f''(t)$.
But this doesn't clarify why the summation of derivatives scaled by $t^n$  would overshoot the target and how scaling by $\frac{1}{n!}$ is an effective mitigation.
I feel that I am missing some obvious intuition here. Perhaps, a geometric interpretation if available?
Edit: The sum of derivatives is greater than the point to be estimated. After mulling it over, acceleration's effect on position is in terms of velocity. $t^2f''(t)$ gives position but its in relation to velocity, which accumulates over time as described by $f'(t)$. So we need to dampen the change in position attributable to acceleration because this effect is in terms of velocity, which is not constant. Overall, each derivative contributes exponentially less to position because its effect on position depends on the previous derivative, which is not constant.

$e^x=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Use \sum for sums, not \Sigma

@SineoftheTime is $\Sigma_{n \ge 0}$ synonymous with $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}$? I would guess so

That's correct .

A Taylor series is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$, but I would not consider $\frac{1}{n!}$ a “scaling factor.“ What exactly do you mean with “overshooting”?

I've often wondered if, in some sense, $\frac{x^n}{n!}$  in Taylor series can be made to represent the hypervolume of points in a simplex - either of the simplex of $(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with  $0<x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n<x$ or  the one with$x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_n<x.$

I guess OP was expecting to have something like $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty w_n f^n(0) x^n$ to be a weighted average in the sense that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty w_n = 1$.  I don't know what to say except, well, that's not how Taylor series work. To get a feeling for why the weights $w_n = 1/n!$ would do the job, I would start with a polynomial like $f(x) = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_0$ and note that $a_n = f^n(0) / n!$.

Since it hasn't been stated explicitly here, your sum is missing the initial $n = 0$ term so the series converges to $e - 1$.

Especially after some reductions-to-simpler-cases, we can see that those factorials "are what they have to be", for reasons you've already anticipated.
So, again, to be clear, anticipate that the infinite Taylor expansion (which may or may not converge, in general) of differentiable $f$, expanded at $z_o$, is of the form $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}w_n\cdot f^{(n)}(z_o)(z-z_o)^n$ (without worrying toooo much about the sense of equality). This should certainly apply to $f(z)=(z-z_o)^N$ for all non-negative integers $N$, from which we discover $(z-z_o)^N=w_N\cdot N! \cdot (z-z_o)^N$. So $w_N=1/N!$. So there's no alternative.
From the other side, since the map from functions to Taylor series is linear, we know that these weights also work for any polynomial.
(Issues about convergence more generally are less elementary, less algebraic.)
